# How to return jQuery data to main class in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am new to typescript + JQuery environment. My question is very simple. At one place, I am calling this function in a typescript class. Let's say, class DatePicker.

```
Class DatePicker {
private pickerData;
    public update() {
         thisi.pickerData = '';
         $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker: any) {
            // return "picker" object to Class level property "pickerData"
          });
   }
}
```

The method is getting called and I want to return "picker" object outside jQuery function and assign it to pickerData. Inside jQuery, Class 'this' is not accessible and I want to avoid using static properties in class as I want to return flow to class from jQuery function. Any help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Correct answer. Thank you @Taplar

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found in another thread of Stack Overflow. Here is the link and short answer I implemented.

[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback][1])

**Using Arrow function-**

If you use function keyword as parameter this points inside the .on function. Arrow function gives you access to 'this' class/container.

```
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', (ev, picker: any) => {
            this.pickerData = picker;
          });
```

Comment: Keep in mind that arrow functions do not work in IE.  They only work in MS Edge.  So if you are concerned with compatibility and you do not use a transpiler like babel to transpile to ES5, you'll have issues with users in IE.

Comment: Thank you @Taplar. Yes, I am using custom visual Power BI with proper web pack configuration including babel and ES5.